# Android Development guidance for experienced Web dev?

Tags: android

**Question**

Where can I find really good, thorough and comprehensive Android development instruction that goes beyond the basics and ties it all together -- with the minimum time investment and almost-zero budget?

**Details**

Please don't mistake me -- I understand that learning a new platform takes time. I'm just looking to streamline the process a bit. Here's my situation:

I've been a PHP-focused web developer for years, and have built numerous large applications around MVC and enterprise design patterns. I have a *small* amount of Java, C++, and C# experience -- mostly what I learned in school, but that was several years ago.

But now I've got to dive in and get up and running building Android applications. I've got a couple of apps that really need building, and the timeframe is simply "ASAP".

I know enough of the basics and I've already been through the Hello World and Notepad tutorials on http://developer.android.com, so I really don't need to start from scratch, but it seems like most of what I've found falls into one of two camps:

1. Very basic tutorials, which spend more time telling you how to set up the environment than actually design a real-world application, or'
2. Highly specific "how to" content, which is great for handling very specific scenarios, but not great for learning to organize and implement professional quality apps.

What I'm looking for ideally is a tutorial series, a book, or some well-documented sample applications that actually clearly demonstrate the why and how of designing building professional android applications -- constructing the model, laying out complex views, etc, without necessarily assuming that I'm a Java expert.

So, any good recommendations ?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I'm not a complete moron in this area. I've built a couple small Android apps already. The problem is that they're simple and not at all professional or release-worthy, and I'm really not sure where to start when it comes to learning "the right way".

All I'm asking for is some very focused tutorials or guidance, ideally geared toward the the professional coming from another platform. I'm NOT asking for someone to magically teach me how to program.

*Side-note: If you're going to down-vote, LEAVE A COMMENT so I at least know what your problem is.*

Comment: Maybe you could find someone interested in helping you out in person by locating a developer group, for example at http://android-developers.meetup.com/. In my city, there's several developer groups who meet specifically to help each other write code.

Comment: Wow, -3 and no comments!?? What gives?

Comment: @ DOK -- That's a good idea, actually, thanks. I'm glad a few people are taking my question seriously..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found these ones rather helpful: [CommonsWare Library](http://commonsware.com/books).

However the official dev Android portal (http://developer.android.com) with its development guides really provides a great foundation which I'd highly recommend to take as the first source of info. Those guides are just musts.

**UPDATE:** Since you come from PHP, then I suspect Android application life-cylce would be a quite new concept for you. Make sure to point additional attention to [Process lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) and [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle). There is so many crappy apps written without understanding of that. Android is able to break your mind if you don't grasp those concepts fully. They are somewhat new in mobile app development, so it takes time to adopt them.

Comment: Thanks for understanding where I'm coming from, Arhimed. Naturally I always start at the official dev guide, but you're right that Android is very different from the platforms with which I'm most familiar. I appreciate the great recommendations and advice.

Answer (score 2):

- [Android for Programmers; an App-driven Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132121360)
- [Android Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005PZ0870)
- [Android Developer's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043GVZDS)

"ASAP" isn't relevant. Don't know the platform, don't know the language, don't know the libraries, you're at the mercy of the tutorials. You'd be better served by spending time not working on the apps in the beginning. Ultimately you'll spend less time if you focus on learning up-front.

Comment: I appreciate the great links. That's all I'm asking for. And obviously I understand that it takes time to learn the platform. But I'm a very hands-on learner; I learn best by doing.

Comment: @BrianLacy The app-driven book is kind of nice in that regard, moreso than many other books it really emphasizes building a single app per chapter (or group of chapters, I forget). It may not be too great as reference material, but that's what the other ones are for.

Comment: Fortunately, there is no shortage of reference material on the web (nor indeed on the bookshelves). The Android Developer Guide and API reference are both very good.